# Error configure services on localhost

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, service, graphite, grafana

I am having trouble to configure some services on my local machine such:

**Webserver**, Port 80

**graphite**, port 8080

**grafana**, port xxx /domain

> **installed services**:
>    - apache2 (it was..)
>    - postgresql (9.5)
>    - carbon

Graphite and grafana were [configured accordingly](https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/monitoring/deploy-graphite-with-grafana-on-ubuntu-14-04).
Also tried other configurations but could not access graphana and write data into graphite.

I could see the graphite interface but the graph never updated/receiving data.

I've also removed and install the services again.

Now after stopping apache2, I could not start it again.

**Error code:**

```
sudo service apache2 restart 
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Not sure what is the issue and how to solve it.

Would appreciate some help for a debugging here. 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There are a few more questions I'd ask myself first.

1. You said you stopped apache. That means a restart isn't technically what you want. What happens when you run

   sudo service apache2 start
2. Have you run the commands suggested in the error message you posted? What output did they provide?
3. What OS? Have you checked ports using netstat or lsof?
4. Is it possible you have a process that might grab 80 while you weren't looking (like skype) or is this a headless server?

Comment: I can't start/restart/reload apache, same error. How can I see what is using port 8080 or what the is the conflict that I'm facing?

Comment: You should also run through the other 3 questions I added there - what's the output of "systemctl status apache2.service" for example?

Comment: On a mac you can use lsof -i {port}, on others typically netstat -p with a  grep. Here's output of lsof on my mac:

lsof -i tcp:3001
COMMAND   PID           USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    96349 keithnordstrom   12u  IPv6 0xafe46a86dff2d9c7      0t0  TCP *:redwood-broker (LISTEN)

Comment: If your OS supports netstat -p option, you can use "netstat -plnt" for details

Comment: What's the negative rating for? Have you solved the problem?

Comment: no haven't. I gave it a couple tries and stopped working on this. And all you said is verified or some points are irrelevant. Issue here is `status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe"`

Comment: OK so you haven't solved the problem, you're no longer interested in solving the problem ... and you don't want to give me information to help me help you solve it. So you've marked me negatively for asking! Good luck.